# How can i import hidden files with python?

Tags: python, import

main.py

```
import .module as m
m.func()
```

.module.py

```
def func():
    print('test')
```

error

```
import .module
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

both files are in the same dir and it works if i remove the dot but i want the file to be hidden because its not a necessary file.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand. How can the file be "not necessary" if you are going to `import` it and call functions from it? You are not meant to be able to name the files however you want and also use the normal `import` mechanism. You would also have problems if the file name had spaces in it, for example, or began with a digit.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that starting the file name with a `.` does not *inherently* make it "hidden"; that is just a convention that your operating system implements.